# I wanted to create an app which can convert any pdf file to stream of text and diagrams like a word document

Tags: parsing, pdf, pdf-conversion

I want to write it from scratch so dont want to use existing pdf parsing libraries. Where and how should I start?

Comment: I voted you -1 and here's why .. "I would like to earn a million dollars, please tell me how to start"

Comment: @KevinBrown actually I never thought of making millions out of it....there are tons of apps already out there for this purpose and a lot of them are free also. All I wanted to do was learn to handle text and I lacked experience in that, didn't knew where to start so I though of asking for help from someone who knows more than me and doesn't mind guiding others, someone like you showed up who start judging people without the effort of knowing them!!

Answer (score 0):

You should read the pdf references and read about the different versions of pdfs and how they are structured.

I hope you know that this will take much time (at least over hundreds of hours). It'd be easier to use a existing library if you have the possibility

Here's the reference for PDF Version 1.7 http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf